# Listing celery tasks as foreignkeys

Tags: python, django, django-celery

Is it possible to let the user select a task from the available shared tasks in a django model? So each app might have tasks.py in it, but they are all @shared_tasks and I would like the user to be able to select a task from a list.

For example:

```
@shared_task
def create_event(incoming):
    print "create an event"


class Module(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    task = models.ForeignKey(ShareTasks)
```

Comment: Sure. `django-celery-results` implements a model for this. You could probably use or borrow the ideas from [that model](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-results/blob/master/django_celery_results/models.py). If you install that extension, they have a task picker in the admin interface.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a backend that stores the results in a django database. That is django-celery-results package, see how to configure it [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-celery-results-using-the-django-orm-cache-as-a-result-backend).

Then you just have to make a foreign key to the appripriate model, ie.

```
task = models.ForeignKey('celery_results.TaskResult')
```